# How to return a Matrices from C function to lua?

Tags: c, lua

How to return a Matrices from C function to lua?

Like this:

```
  mt = {}          -- create the matrix
  for i=1,3 do
     mt[i] = {}     -- create a new row
  for j=1,3 do
    mt[i][j] = 0
  end
end
```

Comment: Rewrite your Lua code using Lua C API.

Comment: Thanks,I found a solution,let me  have a try.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return a table of tables to Lua from C function, trough a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027148/how-to-return-a-table-of-tables-to-lua-from-c-function-trough-a-for-loop)